# BouncyCastle Signing: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

Tags: java

I am signing my data with RSA under BouncyCastle JCE.

I have signed it using the private key of sender, and verification shall be done with public key of sender.

I have signed the content successfully with the following code:

**SIGN FUNCTION**

```
public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }
```

**SIGN CALLER**

```
String sign = sign( filehash , getPrivate( ibftSenderPrivateKeyPath, "RSA" ) );
```

**getPrivate Function**

```
public static  PrivateKey getPrivate(String filename, String algorithm) throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}
```

Now when I am verifying the message with public key of sender it throws the subjected exception.

**Verification Code Caller**

```
boolean bool = verify(decyrptehash, signature, getPublic( senderPublicPath, "RSA" ) );
```

**Verify Function**

```
public static  boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
    publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

    return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
}
```

**Get Public Function**

```
public static PublicKey getPublic(String filename, String algorithm) throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);

    }
```

**KEY GENERATION**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import Decoder.BASE64Encoder;

public class GenerateRSAKeys{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {



        String publicKeyFilename = null;
        String privateKeyFilename = null;

        publicKeyFilename = "C:\\Users\\imjme1\\Desktop\\Work_backup\\FMS\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\sender_keys\\receiver_publicKey";
        privateKeyFilename = "C:\\Users\\imjme1\\Desktop\\Work_backup\\FMS\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\sender_keys\\receiver_privateKey";

        GenerateRSAKeys generateRSAKeys = new GenerateRSAKeys();

        generateRSAKeys.generate(publicKeyFilename, privateKeyFilename);

    }

    private void generate (String publicKeyFilename, String privateFilename){

        try {

            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            // Create the public and private keys
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            BASE64Encoder b64 = new BASE64Encoder();

            SecureRandom random = createFixedRandom();
            generator.initialize(1024, random);

            KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            Key pubKey = pair.getPublic();
            Key privKey = pair.getPrivate();

            System.out.println("publicKey : " + b64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()));
            System.out.println("privateKey : " + b64.encode(privKey.getEncoded()));

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(publicKeyFilename));
            out.write(b64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()));
            out.close();

            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(privateFilename));
            out.write(b64.encode(privKey.getEncoded()));
            out.close();


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static SecureRandom createFixedRandom()
    {
        return new FixedRand();
    }

    private static class FixedRand extends SecureRandom {

        MessageDigest sha;
        byte[] state;

        FixedRand() {
            try
            {
                this.sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                this.state = sha.digest();
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find SHA-1!");
            }
        }

        public void nextBytes(byte[] bytes){

            int    off = 0;

            sha.update(state);

            while (off < bytes.length)
            {                
                state = sha.digest();

                if (bytes.length - off > state.length)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, bytes, off, state.length);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, bytes, off, bytes.length - off);
                }

                off += state.length;

                sha.update(state);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Before checking for the error in the code, I clearly see one problem:
You need to make sure this line

            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());


run **AT MOST once** in the whole runtime of your program.

Comment: How do you create the keys ?

Comment: @LenaBru I have added the key generation code in my post. please check my update

Comment: @LenaBru However, The encryption is done on Sender end and decryption is done on receiver end. Thats why the addProvider is appended twice. One time in sign function and next time in Verify function

Comment: @LenaBru Actually, if a provider is already present it isn't added again. I agree that `addProvider` should not be called more than once, but it doesn't really matter w.r.t. the functionality of the application.

Comment: The provider is not defined in my Java Security in the JRE. Hence, i had to use a separate jar file and import it.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Why would you be so strange to define `FixedRand`, which is completely insecure? Why not simply use the Sun based providers instead of Bouncy Castle for this kind of functionality? Why do you  stringify everything? You are making a lot of strange decisions here.

Comment: Why FixedRand? I am new to cryptography, need advice over it if you feel its not secure. Please suggest something better, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not sun provider?  because I am using IBM machine for encryption which has IBM JCE and it does not allow private key based encryption; another problem is that when i decrypt the same on windows it throws decrytion error due to Sun provider based decryption.

Comment: What does it mean by stringify everything? can you elaborate please

Comment: Just `new SecureRandom()` should do it. IBM doesn't provide private key based encryption because you should use signatures instead. And stringification is the obnoxious practice of converting everything to text, rather than keeping bytes and numbers in their binary format.

Comment: @maartenBodewes You are right, IBM does not allow it and I changed my process to encryption though public key and decryption through private key. But when I encrypted it from IBM and decrypted on SUN it was throwing decryption error because it was encrypted through different JCE.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I ran this code many many times on android and it does get added again

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that you're using base 64 to write the public key to a file, while you're forgetting to decode the public key after reading it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please let me know where do I have to change? You mean I shall do```b64.getdecoder.decode(getPrivate(privateKeyPAth))``` ?

Comment: Sorry, I simply cannot follow you sometimes. Why are you suddenly talking about the private key now? Yes, you have to base 64 decode after reading from file.

Comment: You just replied the actual question here thats why I asked about that. You are quite helpful, just need bit clarifications.4